# reinterpret cast of std vector of std string

Tags: c++

My compiler does not like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> data = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<std::string>>(lParam);
```

I assume it has a problem with the double `>>` marks? How to fix this?

**UPDATE**

It compiles now, but my program crashes! Why is that? I thought a C++ program was type safe and never crashes once it compiles.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>

BOOL CALLBACK cbEnum(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    std::vector<std::string> data = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<std::string>&>(lParam);
    return TRUE;
}

std::vector<std::string> listWindows()
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;

    EnumWindows(cbEnum, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&result));

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    listWindows();
}
```

Comment: If that really is the problem, just put a space between them: `reinterpret_cast<std::vector<std::string> >(lParam);`. Alternatively, use C++11 or later standards

Comment: Define "does not like". And what are you casting _from_, exactly?

Comment: Thanks, I had to add `&` as `reinterpret_cast<std::vector<std::string>&>(lParam)`. But your space idea led me to the solution.

Comment: What is the type of `lParam`, and why in the world does it make sense to tell the compiler to pretend that it's a vector? Less aggressive version: this cast is probably the wrong thing to do.

Comment: lParam is a windows thingie.

Comment: Well, yes, but **what is its type**? Usually it's some variant of `int`, and the question still remains: what does casting this to a `vector` accomplish?

Comment: Why don't you give us the exact error message instead of "does not like"?

Comment: Its not typesafe if you `reinterpret_cast`

Comment: "I thought a C++ program was type safe and never crashes once it compiles." Oh my. It's been a long time since I've laughed so hard. "It compiles" is **far** from "it works".

Comment: "I thought a C++ program was type safe and never crashes once it compiles."  Now that's funny!  Where did you hear that?  What about `int a[1]; a[-2]=0;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As PaulMcKenzie suggested in the comments, this should work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>

static_assert(sizeof(LPARAM) == sizeof(void *), "LPARAM must be large enough to store a pointer");

constexpr size_t MAX_TITLE_LENGTH = 128;

BOOL CALLBACK cbEnum(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    std::vector<std::string> *data = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<std::string> *>(lParam);

    char title[MAX_TITLE_LENGTH];
    //the title is truncated if it exceeds the limit
    GetWindowText(hwnd, title, static_cast<int>(MAX_TITLE_LENGTH));
    data->push_back(title);

    return TRUE;
}

std::vector<std::string> listWindows()
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;

    EnumWindows(cbEnum, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&result));

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    listWindows();
}
```

Comment: I need this to return a list of Windowed applications that are currently running (like Skype, Chrome, Calc, Notepad. etc..). Lparam is a user defined value in the callback.

Comment: If thats what you want to do then look at this example http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/25280/  notice that the code makes no mention of `std::vector` or `std::string`

Comment: Yes but I want my callback's only job to insert the items into my std::vector, so I can return them as a whole.

Comment: @J.Doe -- Then create a std::vector<std::string> object and pass the address of this object as the `lParam`.  Then inside the Enum function, you cast `lParam` to a **pointer** to a `std::vector<std::string>`.  Like this: `std::vector<std::string>* ptr = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<std::string>*>(lParam);`.  Once you have that, then things like `ptr->push_back(string_data);` will or should work